# How to start transaction and rollback with JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, transactions, jooq

Yes! I have read the docs about

> - jOOQ will never commit or rollback on the Connection (Except for
>     CSV-imports, if explicitly configured in the Import API)
> - jOOQ will never start any transactions.
> - ...

but when I need some transaction management, what is the best practice to do this?

Have I said that I'm a big fan of a way of JOOQ!

Answer (score 12):

*This question was asked at a time when jOOQ did not yet implement a transaction API. As of jOOQ 3.4 onwards, such an API is available and documented here:*

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management

#### Transaction API and its default binding to JDBC

By default, jOOQ binds its (nested) transaction support to the JDBC API directly through a simple, functional API:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .transaction(c -> {
        c.dsl().insertInto(...).execute();
        c.dsl().update(...).execute();
   });
```

... the lambda expression (or more specifically, the [`TransactionalRunnable`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TransactionalRunnable.html)) creates a new transaction at its beginning and commits it upon normal completion, or rolls it back upon exception.

Such transactions can be nested

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .transaction(c1 -> {
        c1.dsl().insertInto(...).execute();
        c1.dsl().transaction(c2 -> {
            c2.dsl().insertInto(...).execute();
        });
        c1.dsl().update(...).execute();
   });
```

... in case of which a [`Savepoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Savepoint.html) will be created at the beginning of the nested transaction and the nested transaction discards the savepoint upon normal completion, or rolls back to it upon exception.

#### Overriding the default JDBC binding

In many applications, you will already have a pre-existing transaction management system, e.g. JTA or Spring TX or something else. In this case, you can either:

- Not use the jOOQ transaction API at all
- Implement your own [`TransactionProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TransactionProvider.html) which implements the semantics of the `begin()`, `commit()`, and `rollback()` operations, e.g. by binding them to Spring.

Comment: Nowadays, JOOQ does have code for transactions. https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/  So I guess this answer should be updated.  StackOverflow discourages questions about "best practice", but I also would like to know.  Inside a transaction you should keep using the same "DSLContext" object, so I guess you must pass that to any method calls.

Comment: @Enwired: Thanks for your ping. I have updated the outdated answer. Don't worry about "best practice" questions. If a question is about understanding the correct behaviour, it should be fine. Feel free to ask a new question if you like. I'll be happy to answer.

Comment: I notice in the outer block you use `DSL.using(configuration)` and inside you use `c1.dsl()`, where `c1` is a configuration.  Would it have made any difference if you used `DSL.using(c1)` ?

Comment: What if the connection we are passing to Jooq has autocommit set to true. Will then also the Jooq transaction work, or do we need to set auto-commit to false manually, before passing the connection to Jooq ?

Comment: @PratikSinghal: jOOQ will set autocommit to false for the scope of a transaction, and restore it back to true afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Transaction control is independent of a DB access layer like what JOOQ provides.

Starting and finishing transactions is probably best handled in the [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) of your application.  See the diagram at that page showing the Service Layer's relationship to lower layers it calls.

See also patterns like [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) or [Transaction Script](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html).

Answer (score 0):

I could find an easy way to do this from this link: http://blog.liftoffllc.in/2014/06/jooq-and-transactions.html.

This answer might give you more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380508/542108