# JOOQ & transactions

Tags: java, sql, transactions, jooq

I've been reading about [transactions & jooq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159842/how-to-start-transaction-and-rollback-with-jooq) but I struggle to see how to implement it in practice.

Let's say I provide JOOQ with a custom `ConnectionProvider` which happens to use a connection pool with autocommit set to false.

The implementation is roughly:

```
@Override public Connection acquire() throws DataAccessException {
    return pool.getConnection();
}

@Override public void release(Connection connection) throws DataAccessException {
    connection.commit();
    connection.close();
}
```

How would I go about wrapping two jooq queries into a single transaction?

It is easy with the DefaultConnectionProvider because there's only one connection - but with a pool I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### jOOQ 3.4 Transaction API

With jOOQ 3.4, a [transaction API](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/) has been added to abstract over JDBC, Spring, or JTA transaction managers. This API can be used with Java 8 as such:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .transaction(ctx -> {
       DSL.using(ctx)
          .update(TABLE)
          .set(TABLE.COL, newValue)
          .where(...)
          .execute();
   });
```

Or with pre-Java 8 syntax

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .transaction(new TransactionRunnable() {
       @Override
       public void run(Configuration ctx) {
           DSL.using(ctx)
              .update(TABLE)
              .set(TABLE.COL, newValue)
              .where(...)
              .execute();
       }
   });
```

The idea is that the lambda expression (or anonymous class) form the transactional code, which:

- Commits upon normal completion
- Rolls back upon exception

The [`org.jooq.TransactionProvider` SPI](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TransactionProvider.html) can be used to override the default behaviour, which implements nestable transactions via JDBC using [`Savepoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Savepoint.html).

#### A Spring example

The current documentation shows an example when using Spring for transaction handling:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-spring/

This example essentially boils down to using a Spring `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`

```
<!-- Using Apache DBCP as a connection pooling library.
     Replace this with your preferred DataSource implementation -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    init-method="createDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/maven-test" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!-- Using Spring JDBC for transaction management -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Bridging Spring JDBC data sources to jOOQ's ConnectionProvider -->
<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" 
      name="connectionProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource" />
</bean>
```

A running example is available from GitHub here:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example

#### A Spring and Guice example

Although I personally wouldn't recommend it, some users have had success replacing a part of Spring's DI by Guice and handle transactions with Guice. There is also an integration-tested running example on GitHub for this use-case:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-guice-example

Comment: Thanks for your answer - do you mind commenting on my proposed solution? (apart from the fact that it is a quick and ugly fix!)

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not the best way but it seems to work. The caveat is that it is not the `release` but the `commit` method which closes the connection and returns it to the pool, which is quite confusing and could lead to issues if some code "forgets" to commit...

So the client code looks like:

```
final PostgresConnectionProvider postgres =
            new PostgresConnectionProvider("localhost", 5432, params.getDbName(), params.getUser(), params.getPass())

private static DSLContext sql = DSL.using(postgres, SQLDialect.POSTGRES, settings);

//execute some statements here
sql.execute(...);

//and don't forget to commit or the connection will not be returned to the pool
PostgresConnectionProvider p = (PostgresConnectionProvider) sql.configuration().connectionProvider();
p.commit();
```

And the ConnectionProvider:

```
public class PostgresConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostgresConnectionProvider.class);

    private final ThreadLocal<Connection> connections = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private final BoneCP pool;

    public PostgresConnectionProvider(String serverName, int port, String schema, String user, String password) throws SQLException {
        this.pool = new ConnectionPool(getConnectionString(serverName, port, schema), user, password).pool;
    }

    private String getConnectionString(String serverName, int port, String schema) {
        return "jdbc:postgresql://" + serverName + ":" + port + "/" + schema;
    }

    public void close() {
        pool.shutdown();
    }

    public void commit() {
        LOG.debug("Committing transaction in {}", Thread.currentThread());
        try {
            Connection connection = connections.get();
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.commit();
                connection.close();
                connections.set(null);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DataAccessException("Could not commit transaction in postgres pool", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Connection acquire() throws DataAccessException {
        LOG.debug("Acquiring connection in {}", Thread.currentThread());
        try {
            Connection connection = connections.get();
            if (connection == null) {
                connection = pool.getConnection();
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                connections.set(connection);
            }
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DataAccessException("Can't acquire connection from postgres pool", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    //no-op => the connection won't be released until it is commited
    public void release(Connection connection) throws DataAccessException {
        LOG.debug("Releasing connection in {}", Thread.currentThread());
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I don't think that your solution is really a "hack" as you put it. Getting connection lifecycles and transaction management right is a non-trivial problem. Maybe, you could add some logging code in the finalizer of the `PostgresConnectionProvider`, which would detect when there is an unreturned connection? I'm going to think about these things a little bit more on my side. I've had a couple of ideas which [I explained in this thread on the user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/iomrnfK9cws/Cs32Wn5ljwYJ)

Comment: Yes good idea. And thanks for the link: I had seen a few discussions but not that one.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way,(I have found) to use Spring Transactions with jOOQ, is given here: http://blog.liftoffllc.in/2014/06/jooq-and-transactions.html

Basically we implement a `ConnectionProvider` that uses `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(ds)` method to find and return the DB connection that holds transaction created by Spring.

Create a `TransactionManager` bean for your `DataSource`, example shown below:

```
  <bean
   id="dataSource"
   class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
   destroy-method="close"

   p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   p:url="mysql://locahost:3306/db_name"
   p:username="root"
   p:password="root"
   p:initialSize="2"
   p:maxActive="10"
   p:maxIdle="5"
   p:minIdle="2"
   p:testOnBorrow="true"
   p:validationQuery="/* ping */ SELECT 1"
  />

  <!-- Configure the PlatformTransactionManager bean -->
  <bean
   id="transactionManager"
   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
   p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
  />
  <!-- Scan for the Transactional annotation -->
  <tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Now you can annotate all the classes or methods which uses jOOQ's `DSLContext` with

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

And while creating the `DSLContext` object jOOQ will make use of the transaction created by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Though its an old question, Please look at this link to help configure JOOQ to use spring provided transaction manager. Your datasource and DSLContext have to be aware of Transacation.

https://www.baeldung.com/jooq-with-spring

You may have to change

```
@Bean
public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
    return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
}
```

to

```
@Bean
public DSLContext dsl() {
    return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
}
```