# Easier way to use transactions in JOOQ

Tags: jooq

We use JOOQ code generation which works like a charm. For 99% of our use cases we simply reuse DAOs generated by JOOQ. For one usecase we need to use transactions.

I am looking at other questions such as the one here [JOOQ & transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046247/jooq-transactions) and using JOOQ transactions to insert rows into two tables as a **transaction**.
The tables are quite big with 15+ columns and I am thinking if there is a better way to do this other than

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .transaction(ctx -> {
       DSL.using(ctx)
          .update(TABLE)
          .set(TABLE.COL, newValue)
          .where(...)
          .execute();
   });
```

Specifying the 15 columns seems like a lot of work which has to be redone when new columns etc are added. We already have POJOs is there any way to simply convert POJO into a record and simply using the DSL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a POJO to a record like this:

```java
ctx.dsl()
   .update(TABLE)
   .set(ctx.dsl().newRecord(TABLE, pojo))
   .where(...)
   .execute();
```

This will set *all* the columns in the table, which may be undesired (e.g. you may not want to set the primary key to itself). To prevent certain fields from being included, use [`Record.changed(Field, boolean)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#changed(org.jooq.Field,boolean)), to reset the internal changed flag per column.

Alternatively, if your `WHERE` clause is just a predicate on the primary key, you can also just use [`UpdatableRecord.update()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html#update()):

```java
ctx.dsl().newRecord(TABLE, pojo).update();
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer @Lukas! There should be a section in the JOOQ doc that explains how we can inter-operate between POJOs and Records. In general I think most developers want to work with POJOs and DAOs unless it is absolutely mandatory.

Comment: @KannanEkanath. *"There should be a section in the JOOQ doc that explains how we can inter-operate between POJOs and Records."* It's documented here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/, *"In general I think most developers want to work with POJOs and DAOs unless it is absolutely mandatory."* I don't think so. jOOQ's core feature is the DSL. You just happen to take a different approach, which is also supported by jOOQ.